# Experiencing weird thing in saving and retrieving data from notepad

Tags: c#, winforms, unicode

Recently i was trying to **save data in notepad with Unicode encoding** but when i tried to retrieve my data from notepad through Unicode encoding it showed up something else. what i **actually saved in notepad is "((char)56774)"** but what i **retrieved from notepad is "((char)65533)"**.

Code is show below:-

```
File.WriteAllText("Foo.txt", ((char)56774).ToString(), Encoding.Unicode);
string s = File.ReadAllText("Foo.txt", Encoding.Unicode);
char[] c = s.ToCharArray();
```

Please tell me where am i going wrong or how should i get the same character back from notepad.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Symbol 65533 is [used to replace an incoming character whose value is unknown or unrepresentable in Unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0fffd/index.htm). That means `((char)56774)` is not a valid Unicode symbol. But why we don't get `EncoderFallbackException` then?

Comment: sir your link explains why 65533 is returned but why is 56774 not a valid unicode?

Comment: i hope someone from [The Unicode Consortium](http://www.unicode.org/consortium/consort.html) will come and explain. Actually this behavior of .NET StreamWriter seems to be strange to me.

Comment: i have sent a mail to them but i don't think so they are going to reply to this soon.

Comment: I might be wrong here but if i remember correctly the way unicode works is that indexes above a certain number need a second 8 byte code to represent a char so if you got 56774 it also reads the next 8 bytes to get the actual char.

Comment: sir i know that it takes 2 byte to read "56774" char but i am just saving the char so it should manage that internally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\uDDC6` is a [low surrogate pair](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) so it more than the character that you've provided in order to form a complete character.

You can confirm that it doesn't support this character by using your own encoder that throws an exception when invalid characters are used.

```
var customEncoder = new UTF8Encoding(true, true);
File.WriteAllText("Foo.txt", ((char)56774).ToString(), customEncoder);
char c = Convert.ToChar(File.ReadAllText("Foo.txt", customEncoder));
```

Notice that this throws an exception when it reads that character, which allows you to know that it is invalid.

Depending on your requirements, you could likely output the bytes directly instead:

```
File.WriteAllBytes("Foo.bin", BitConverter.GetBytes((char)56774));
char writtenCharacter = BitConverter.ToChar(File.ReadAllBytes("Foo.bin"), 0);
```

Comment: sir the code you provided gives us the error that was not displaying before (which is correct) but sir i need to save the char as it is not in any other format like binary or something else . can you help me with it

Comment: @newbee: I just updated my answer to explain how to do this. Just be aware that it won't be human readable anymore.

Comment: sir the answer seems good to me and i will give it a shot btw thanks man